# Old school schema.ini question

Tags: odbc

Anyone know how to specify a custom record delimiter in a schema.ini file? I need to import some data for an old system, and the source file uses pipes (|) as field delimieters and tilda's (~) as row delimiters. I've managed to get the field delimiters configured. Row delimiters anyone?

The current schema.ini file...

```
[sourcefile.txt]
ColNameHeader=false
Format=Delimited(|)
CharacterSet=ANSI
Col1=F1 text
Col2=F2 text
Col3=F3 text
Col4=F4 text
Col5=F5 text
...
```

Oh, and yes, it has to be done this way. I can't work around it by importing it through some other means...

Comment: If you have any more flexibility in your host environment at all there might be other answers.  For example people often say "ODBC" when they mean something else.  If you can use an ADO connection string it might be possible to create an OLEDB Simple Provider to handle this for you.  Aside from that you'll probably have to pre-process the file to change the line-ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no chance: see the [grammar of ODBC text driver text files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms716438%28VS.85%29.aspx), especially these 2 lines:

```
delimited-text-line ::=
   blank-line |
   delimited-data [delimiter delimited-data]... end-of-line
end-of-line ::= <CR> | <LF> | <CR><LF>
```

ie. no setting for a custom row separator. also, no string anywhere related in the dll ...

Comment: Well, that settles that.... I suspected this was the case, but thought I'd give it a go anyway. That's for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a copy of SQL Server, you might want to try the BCP utility which also handles row terminators.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/specify-field-and-row-terminators-sql-server

Back in the day these "old school" formats were relied on to provide consistency of format between different systems (Unix, DOS/Windows etc)